# How to use ng2-currency-mask in angular 6 Project

Tags: angular, input, tags

I'am using ng2-currency-mask module in my Angular 6 project but when apply (change)  method in  input fields its not working

here i used input tag

```
                        <input style="text-align:right; width:260px;" currencyMask  [options]="{ prefix: 'Rs ', thousands: ',', decimal: '.' }" (change)="addToAllChange($event.target.value)" placeholder="Value" class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: can you put together a stackblitz?  or i can try to..  is ng2-currency-mask the name of the library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not able to trigger `change` even because of `currencyMask` directive. You can leverage `ngModel` and `ngModelChange`.

```
<input style="text-align:right; width:260px;" currencyMask  
  [options]="{ prefix: 'Rs ', thousands: ',', decimal: '.' }" 
  #currency
  (ngModelChange)="addToAllChange(currency.value)" 
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  placeholder="Value" 
  class="form-control"/>
```

If you want to control on when it should be updated, you can use `ngModelOption`.

Comment: don't work with me, (keyup) works with little bugs

Comment: @Edward - Are you getting any error in console ?